# how to use native drawer in react native

Tags: android, react-native, drawerlayout

I have started with react native. I am using react native components to create a drawer that will be opened with the click of the button in the title bar.

But the drawer does not open on the whole screen. This is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, DrawerLayoutAndroid, Text, Alert, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Icon} from '@shoutem/ui'

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }

  openDrawer() {
    this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer()
  }
  render() {

    var navigationView = (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left' }}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>
      </View>
    );
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 100, backgroundColor: 'rgb(240,240,240)' }}>
        <DrawerLayoutAndroid
          drawerWidth={200}
          ref={'DRAWER'}
          drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
          drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
          renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
          {
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start', flexDirection: 'row' }}>

              <Icon onPress={() => {
                this.openDrawer();
              }} style={{ flex: 0.1, marginTop: 2, marginLeft: 2 }} name="sidebar" />

              <View style={{ flex: 0.25 }}></View>

              <Picker style={{ flex: 0.3, marginTop: -10, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
                selectedValue={this.state.selectedCategory}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ selectedCategory: itemValue })}>
                <Picker.Item label="Patient" value="patient" />
                <Picker.Item label="Student" value="student" />
              </Picker>

              <View style={{ flex: 0.25 }}></View>

              <Icon onPress={() => {
                Alert.alert('Title', 'Long Message');
              }} style={{ marginTop: 2, marginRight: 2, flex: 0.1 }} name="add-friend" />
            </View>
          }
        </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the view

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this? And I have written the whole code in title bar, I guess this is not the correct way, how can out the title bar code? Please ignore if this is too basic to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawer takes the height of its parent component (here it's a `<View/>`). And as you set the height of the parent `<View/>` to `100`your Drawer has the same height.

Here is the example in [React-Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html):

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={300}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => navigatenter code hereionView}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
    </View>
</DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

Comment: so how can I  rearrange my components so that it will give the desired result?

Comment: Remove the parent `<View />`